# Time Distorted Areas?

Tags: dnd-5e

Is there any way to create or find an area that has time distortion i.e. isolate yourself for decades inside this place only to come out the exact time you went in.

Comment: Hi Gavin, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] when you have a moment. I'm not quite sure what this question is trying to ask. Is this about whether such things exist in a particular setting (e.g. Forgotten Realms) or whether there are rules around such things (e.g. certain spells, etc)?

Comment: It may also help if you explain *why* you want to do this. Are you a player or are you a DM and this is for a NPC?

Answer (score 4):

## No

There is no way to completely stop time for such a duration. Even allowing a short time to pass eg. 24 hours would allow the party to completely rest up without any danger.

The closest I can think of is the time warp effect from visiting the Feywild. Check page 50 of the dungeon masters guide for details.

Answer (score 0):

## You cannot create an area, but finding may be possible.

First things first; finding is always a possibility, since anything the DM thinks up can become real, but creating doesn't seem possible anymore. (For finding, the Feywild is a good example)

In pathfinder the *Demiplane* spell allowed you to slow time down (with some additional cost). But in 5e there doesn't seem an option to do this with its *Demiplane* spell.

There are spells which makes time move faster for yourself like *Sequester*, but this is basically a *100 year sleep* gimmick, which isn't what you're looking for.

The only spell that stops time is the 9th level spell *Time Stop*, which stops time for a couple of turns:

> You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself. No time passes for other creatures, while you take 1d4 + 1 turns in a row, during which you can use actions and move as normal. This spell ends if one of the actions you use during this period, or any effects that you create during this period, affects a creature other than you or an object being worn or carried by someone other than you.
>
> In addition, the spell ends if you move to a place more than 1,000 feet from the location where you cast it.

Sidenote, you can always try and talk to the DM to alter *Demiplane*.

Comment: Would anyone mind telling me what's wrong with the answer so that I can keep it in mind for the future?

Comment: I upvoted this. But the downvote may be because of a poor/confusing title. Other than that I don't know what is wrong with this.

Comment: Your recommendation of using *slow* in a homebrew way without saying if you'd used it this way at the table and what ramifications were was why I downvoted.